# floating right sidebar menu ath the middle of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I have a table with two columns, which shows under the header of my website.
The header is quite large, so in order to see the table you need to scroll down a bit.

In the left column of the table I have some long articles for the reader, and in the right column I would like to disply a floating right sidebar menu, which acts normally until you scroll to it(I mean it doesnt pass its table's higher limit), but after you scroll down and pass it, it keeps its position at the top of the screen.

I have tried

```
 position:fixed ; top: 1em; right: 1em;
```

but this displays the sidebar at the top of the website, floating over the header, in the top-right corner of the screen.
I would like to keep its position relative to the table, and not to the whole screen. How do you suggest I should proceed?

Comment: Can you please set up a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I would like for it it to act exactly like the right sidebar bar from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask  ----> after the advice... after you click ok, and proceed from the bottom of the page

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. You said you want a right hand side sidebar. What you have not done is told us what you have already tried. The best way is to set up an online demo, such as on http://jsfiddle.net where we can play with what you have already done.

Comment: In the question i said I have tried to put a div in the right column of the table, with the style 
 position:fixed ; top: 1em; right: 1em;   --- but it is not keeping its position inside the contents of the table column, in the top-right. instead, it displays it at the right-top corner of the whole website

Comment: I give up. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Good luck to you too!

Comment: @KlaussGekker: You cannot expect people to help you before you show them your efforts. Here read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Red flag number 1, it appears you are using tables for layout, this is generally not good practice! Please show us more than the CSS. Provide some context in the form of HTML for the relative elements. We need to be able to replicate what you have done so we can proceed to help. Providng one line of CSS will not enable us to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, guys! I have figured it out using the following code and now it works perfectly

```
    function moveScroller() {
    var move = function() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
    var s = $("#scroller");
    if(st > ot) {
        s.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: "0px"
        });
    } else {
        if(st <= ot) {
            s.css({
                position: "relative",
                top: ""
            });
        }
    }
};
$(window).scroll(move);
move();
   }



    <div id="sidebar" style="width:270px;"> 
    <div id="scroller-anchor"></div> 
   <div id="scroller" style="margin-top:10px; width:270px"> 
    Scroller Scroller Scroller
   </div>
  </div>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
   moveScroller();
  });
 </script>
```